# Adding Frequent words to Dataframe while applying n-gram pattern in NLP in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, nltk

Scenario is, that I'm categorizing tweets into 6 different Polarities viz. Positive, Moderately Positive, Highly Positive, Negative, Moderately Negative and Highly Negative.

Since, this procedure undergoes through steps of NLP (using NLTK) I need to go sentence / tweet by tweet.

**The Problem:**
These polarities are defined by patters after POS tagging. One of the Pattern includes: Verb + Verb + Adjective includes in D (Drought related terms) and in F (Frequent words)

I need those Frequent words, that change this sentence into any of those 6 Polarities to be saved into my dataframe.

**Snippet:**
Here's what I tried

```
for (w1, tag1), (w2, tag2), (w3, tag3) in nltk.trigrams(PoS_TAGS):
    if tag1.startswith("RB") and tag2.startswith("RB") and tag3.startswith("JJ"):
        tri_pairs.append((w1, w2, w3))
        if tri_pairs[0] or tri_pairs[1] or tri_pairs[2] in D:
            print("[True]: Tri Pairs are found in Drought Rel. Term")

            for j in range(len(F)):
                if tri_pairs[0] or tri_pairs[1] or tri_pairs[2] in F[j]:
                    print("[True]: Tri Pairs are found in Frequent Wordset")
                    if RES is "Positive":
                        RES = "Highly Positive"
                    elif RES is "Negative":
                        RES = "Highly Negative"
                    print "="*25,F[j]
                    FW_list.append(F[j])
                else:
                    print"[False]: Doesn't Match with Frequent Wordset\n"

        else:
            print"[False]: Tri Pairs Matched Nowhere in D\n"
    else:
        print "[TriPair(F)]: Pattern for Adverb, Adverb, Adjective did not match.\n Looking for Bi-Pair Patterns\n"
print(tri_pairs)
print(">"*13,FW)
```

As you can notice, I tried to print in most ways using List or even inside loop. Both have returned nothing useful. Similarly, other two patterns decide left out polarities.

I have also written code to add it in dataframe:

```
fuzzy_df = fuzzy_df.append({'Tweets': tweets[i], 'Classified': RES, 'FreqWord': FW}, ignore_index=True)
```

but so far the csv is returned blank for that column.

### Edit 1:

Frequent words are already available with me. They are as follows:

```
>>> F
['drought', 'water', 'love', 'rain', 'year', 'famine', 'farmers', 'crops', 'south', 'http', 'europe', 'scarcity', 'near', 'thought', 'ever', 'devastates', 'feed', 'message', 'eduaubdedubu', 'instant', 'italy', 'severe', 'by', 'beaches', 'wildfires', 'heat', 'us']
```

### Edit 2

CSV looks like this:

```
Tweets,Classified,FreqWord
 real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Negative,
 calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive,
 love thought drought,Positive,
 neville rooney end ever tons trophy drought,Positive,
 lakes drought,Positive,
 lakes fan joint trailblazers dot forget play drought,Positive,
 reign mother kerr funny none tried make come back drought,Positive,
 wonder could help thai market b post reuters drought devastates south europe crops,Negative,
```

INPUT File:

```
tweets,polarity
real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Positive
calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive
hate thought drought,Negative
```

Although, the output I've shown above is tokenized and stop words are also removed.

EXPECTED OUTPUT FILE:

```
Tweets,Classified,FreqWord
     real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Negative,water
     calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive,drought
     love thought drought,Positive,drought
     neville rooney end ever tons trophy drought,Positive,rain
     lakes drought,Positive,drought
     lakes fan joint trailblazers dot forget play drought,Positive,farmer
     reign mother kerr funny none tried make come back drought,Positive,crops
     wonder could help thai market b post reuters drought devastates south europe crops,Negative,crops
```

### Edit 3

```
FW = ''
for i in range(len(tweets)):
    sent = nltk.word_tokenize(tweets[i])
    PoS_TAGS = nltk.pos_tag(sent)

    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
    sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

    one_sentence = tweets.iloc[i]
    scores = sia.polarity_scores(text=one_sentence)
    print "POS:", scores.get('pos')
    print "NEG:", scores.get('neg')
    print "NEU:", scores.get('neu')

    POS = scores.get('pos')
    NEG = scores.get('neg')
    NEU = scores.get('neu')
    RES = str()

    if POS > NEG:
        RES = 'Positive'
    elif NEG > POS:
        RES = 'Negative'
    elif NEU >= 0.5 or POS > NEU:
        RES = 'Positive'
    elif NEU < 0.5:
        RES = 'Negative'

    # -------------------------------------------------------- PATTERN ADVERB, ADVERB, ADJECTIVE (Down)
    tri_pairs = list()
    for (w1, tag1), (w2, tag2), (w3, tag3) in nltk.trigrams(PoS_TAGS):
        if tag1.startswith("RB") and tag2.startswith("RB") and tag3.startswith("JJ"):
            tri_pairs.append((w1, w2, w3))
            if tri_pairs[0] or tri_pairs[1] or tri_pairs[2] in D:
                print("[True]: Tri Pairs are found in Drought Rel. Term")
                # TRIGGER AREA
                for j in range(len(F)):
                    if tri_pairs[0] or tri_pairs[1] or tri_pairs[2] in F[j]:
                        print("[True]: Tri Pairs are found in Frequent Wordset")
                        if RES is "Positive":
                            RES = "Highly Positive"
                            FW = F[j]
                            #fuzzy_df['FreqWord'].map(lambda x: next((y for y in x.split() if y in F), 'Not Found'))
                        elif RES is "Negative":
                            RES = "Highly Negative"
                            FW = F[j]
                    else:
                        print"[False]: Doesn't Match with Frequent Wordset\n"

            else:
                print"[False]: Tri Pairs Matched Nowhere in D\n"

        else:
            print "[TriPair(F)]: Pattern for Adverb, Adverb, Adjective did not match.\n Looking for Bi-Pair Patterns\n"
    print(tri_pairs)

    # -------------------------------------------------------- PATTERN ADVERB, ADJECTIVE (Down)
    bi_pairs = list()
    for (w1, tag1), (w2, tag2) in nltk.bigrams(PoS_TAGS):
        if tag1.startswith("RB") and tag2.startswith("JJ"):
            bi_pairs.append((w1, w2))

            if bi_pairs[0] or bi_pairs[1] in D:
                print("[True]: Bi Pairs are found in Drought Rel. Term")

                for k in range(len(F)):
                    if bi_pairs[0] or bi_pairs[1] is F[k]:
                        print("[True]: Bi Pairs are found in Frequent Wordset")
                        if RES is "Positive":
                            RES = "Moderately Positive"
                            FW = F[k]
                        elif RES is "Negative":
                            RES = "Moderately Negative"
                            FW = F[k]
                    else:
                        print("[False]: Bi Pairs found missing in Freq. Wordset")

            else:
                print("[False]: Bi Pairs Matched Nowhere in D")

        else:
            print("[BiPair(F)]: Pattern Not Matched, Looking for Mono Pattern")
    print(bi_pairs)

    # -------------------------------------------------------- PATTERN ADJECTIVE (Down)
    for w, tag in PoS_TAGS:
        print w, " - ", tag
        if tag.startswith("JJ"):
            if w in D:
                print("Matched with D")
                for l in range(len(F)):
                    if w is F[l]:
                        print("Matched with F")
                        if RES is "Positive":
                            RES = "Positive"
                            FW = F[l]
                        elif RES is "Negative":
                            RES = "Negative"
                            FW = F[l]
                    else:
                        print("Unmatched in F")
                        FW = F[l] in sent
            else:
                print("Unmatched in D")
        else:
            print w, "is not an ADJECTIVE"


# -------------------------------------------------------- MAKING ENTRY OF RECORDS OF TWEETS and POLARITY RESULT
    fuzzy_df = fuzzy_df.append({'Tweets': tweets[i], 'Classified': RES, 'FreqWord': FW}, ignore_index=True)
# ADDING RECORDS IN DATAFRAME
fuzzy_df.to_csv("fuzzy.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I've understood you. But to get frequent words, can't you just do nltk.tokenize, get count per word, sort it in descending order and get the top frequent words ?

Comment: I already have the Frequent words stored in a list. I'll update the question with list F values @ManishSaraswat

Comment: Do you have an example csv file?

Comment: @alvas sure, please check edit 2

Comment: Also, do you have a sample input file and the desired output that you hope to get?

Comment: @alvas sure, please check edit 2

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

open_strio = io.StringIO("""Tweets,Classified,FreqWord
real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Negative,
calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive,
love thought drought,Positive,
neville rooney end ever tons trophy drought,Positive,
lakes drought,Positive,
lakes fan joint trailblazers dot forget play drought,Positive,
reign mother kerr funny none tried make come back drought,Positive,
wonder could help thai market b post reuters drought devastates south europe crops,Negative,""")

with open_strio as fin:
    df = pd.read_csv(open_strio)


dictionary = Counter(['drought', 'water', 'love', 'rain', 'year', 'famine', 'farmers', 'crops', 'south', 'http', 'europe', 'scarcity', 'near', 'thought', 'ever', 'devastates', 'feed', 'message', 'eduaubdedubu', 'instant', 'italy', 'severe', 'by', 'beaches', 'wildfires', 'heat', 'us'])

df['FreqCounter'] = df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split()) & dictionary)
df['FreqWord'] = df['FreqCounter'].apply(lambda x: list(x.keys()))
```

First create a simple `Counter()` object from the list of defined words (i.e. `dictionary`).

Then apply the `Counter()` intersection to each row of tweet to create the `df['FreqCounter']` column.

Lastly, extract the set of unique keys from the `df['FreqCounter']` to populate `df['FreqWord']`

---

If you don't need the counters of the words in the `dictionary` per row of tweet, you can simple use a set, i.e.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

open_strio = io.StringIO("""Tweets,Classified,FreqWord
real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Negative,
calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive,
love thought drought,Positive,
neville rooney end ever tons trophy drought,Positive,
lakes drought,Positive,
lakes fan joint trailblazers dot forget play drought,Positive,
reign mother kerr funny none tried make come back drought,Positive,
wonder could help thai market b post reuters drought devastates south europe crops,Negative,""")

with open_strio as fin:
    df = pd.read_csv(open_strio)


dictionary = set(['drought', 'water', 'love', 'rain', 'year', 'famine', 'farmers', 'crops', 'south', 'http', 'europe', 'scarcity', 'near', 'thought', 'ever', 'devastates', 'feed', 'message', 'eduaubdedubu', 'instant', 'italy', 'severe', 'by', 'beaches', 'wildfires', 'heat', 'us'])

df['FreqWord'] = df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split()) & dictionary)
```

---

If you want the most frequent word out of the `df['FreqCounter']`, then:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

open_strio = io.StringIO("""Tweets,Classified,FreqWord
real time strategy password wastelands depletion groundwater skyrocketing debts make years anantapur drought worse,Negative,
calm director day science meetings nasal talk cutting edge remote sensing research drought veg fluorescence calm love,Positive,
love thought drought,Positive,
neville rooney end ever tons trophy drought,Positive,
lakes drought,Positive,
lakes fan joint trailblazers dot forget play drought,Positive,
reign mother kerr funny none tried make come back drought,Positive,
wonder could help thai market b post reuters drought devastates south europe crops,Negative,""")

with open_strio as fin:
    df = pd.read_csv(open_strio)


dictionary = Counter(['drought', 'water', 'love', 'rain', 'year', 'famine', 'farmers', 'crops', 'south', 'http', 'europe', 'scarcity', 'near', 'thought', 'ever', 'devastates', 'feed', 'message', 'eduaubdedubu', 'instant', 'italy', 'severe', 'by', 'beaches', 'wildfires', 'heat', 'us'])

df['FreqCounter'] = df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split()) & dictionary)
df['FreqWord'] = df['FreqCounter'].apply(lambda x: x.most_common()[0][0])
```

Comment: Hey Alvas, I tried this. This leaves my `FreqWord` columns with list in it. For further processing, I'll have to extract as a list first. Resulting into more lines of code. Also, there could be only one element from list of Frequent words.

Comment: Hi Alvas, I have added more to perspective. you may check Edit 3 if you will. That might add more insight.

Comment: adding more code won't help, you have to be more specific about what you need.

Comment: Very true. The Tweet since it is being splitted into those patterns, I need those patterns to decide which frequent word is impacting the tweet. Based on that I'll need to store it into dataframe. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using this minimal example, you can try this simple way too: 
`next` will iterate through rows of tweets, check if any frequent word is available in the tweet, if not it will return `Not Found`.

```
# sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['I am going somewhere','tomorrow is holiday']})

# list of frequent words
lst = ['holiday','am']

# check if any word in tweets exist in list of frequent words
df['freq'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: next((y for y in x.split() if y in lst), 'Not Found'))

print(df)
    name                    freq
0   I am going somewhere    am
1   tomorrow is holiday     holiday
```

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: Hey Manish, Tried this. Quite close to my solution, however notice the inner for loop. I need this frequent word to be decided inside if-else statements. Can we tweak it?

Comment: you mean the list of frequent words to be generated inside if-else statement ? Isn't the frequent words list based on entire vocabulary?

Comment: Well, If you notice the tweet is taken into words and I need to find out which pattern sets the paorality and with what frequent word. So at the end of 3 patterns I write the value / freq word into df. `fuzzy_df = fuzzy_df.append({'Tweets': tweets[i], 'Classified': RES, 'FreqWord': FW}, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: You might want to check the edit 3. I hope that it gives some insight.

Comment: @T3J45 Adding more code doesn't help me. I'm sorry. Just to be sure, you want output to be, for every tweet you want to find the word in the frequent list, and polarity is already available in the input data you've shown above. So, that's all ?

Comment: Very true. The Tweet since it is being splitted into those patterns, I need those patterns to decide which frequent word is impacting the tweet. Based on that I'll need to store it into dataframe. I hope this helps.